# Открытие текстового файла

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно через программу открыть текстовый файл, но не для работы в программе, а просто для просмотра. Например просто запустить в блокноте. Есть какая нибудь функция?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться [WinExec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx)

в качестве параметров `notepad path\to\file`

Answer (score 1):

`system("notepad.exe filename")`

Если расширение зарегистрировано в системе - то хватит и просто имени файла:

`system("filename.txt")`

Comment: @AMANOR Ну, если вас ответ устраивает - ставьте птичку :)